# Position background image of anchor to the left of anchor text?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I'm trying to get the background image I set for the anchor to act as an icon, next to the anchor text and resized down - so that the image and text are in-line with each other, but I'm not sure how to do this.

### Code:

```css
a {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

```html
<a style="background: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-128.png');">
    Text here
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code.

```css
a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  background-image: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ninja-things-1/1772/ninja-simple-128.png');
  background-size: 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Text here</a>
```